# kivy- need to wait until the thread is finish

Tags: multithreading, kivy

I have in my app a thread that appends something to a list and then I want to `print` it on another screen, but the program runs the thread after the `print` and it gave me error that there is no thing in my list. I need to stop the program until the thread is done, how can I do this? I tried to use `.join()` but it didn't work... thanks for help, my app:

```py
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text='username'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

        self.submit_button = Button(text='sumbit',size_hint=(.5, .25),font_size=20)
        self.submit_button.bind(on_press=self.submit_username)
        self.add_widget(self.submit_button)


    def submit_username(self, *args):
        self.msg=threading.Thread(target=send_data(self.username.text))
        self.msg.start()
        self.msg.join()
        sm.current = 'searchi'
        sm.transition.direction = 'left'


def send_data(name):
    my_socket = socket.socket()
    my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8093))
    my_socket.send(name.encode('utf-8'))
    name,address = my_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    msg = name.decode('utf-8')
    alist.append(msg)
    my_socket.close()

# Declare both screens

class Searchi(Screen):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Searchi, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Label(text=alist[0]))
```

the list have to `msg` if i am delete the line `self.add_widget(Label(text=alist[0]))` then it is no problem in the recv line. i just need to wait until the thread is finished.

Comment: Did the answer i posted help you?

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with a Thread if you are going to wait for it anyway? You could just call send_data(self.username.text) and be done with it.

But doing this is usually bad practice (doing blocking calls without a thread, or waiting for the thread to finish in a blocking way, which is equivalent), what you want, instead of waiting for the task to be done before proceeding, is to react to the task being done, that is, at the end of your thread, do something that will allow your app to proceed.

you could have a callback to move your user to the new screen, called at the end of the thread.

```
def submit_username(self, *args):
    def callback():
        sm.current = 'searchi'
        sm.transition.direction = 'left'
    threading.Thread(target=send_data(self.username.text, callback).start()

def send_data(name, callback):
    my_socket = socket.socket()
    my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8093))
    my_socket.send(name.encode('utf-8'))
    name,address = my_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    msg = name.decode('utf-8')
    alist.append(msg)
    my_socket.close()
    callback()
```

if you want your user to touch anything while the action happens, i would advise putting a Popup with auto_dismiss=False, and a content indicating that data is being processed, and to close it in the callback.